# Azure DevOps Deploy Release step on Failure

Tags: azure-devops

Our structure for a release in azure devops is to

deploy our app to our DEV environment.
Kick off my Selenium (Visual Studio) tests against that environment.
If passes, moves to our TEST environment.
If fails/hard stop.
We want to add new piece/functionality, starts same as above, Except instead of hard stop. 5) if default step fails, continue to next step. 6) New detail testing starts (turns on screen recorder)

The new detailed step has 'Agent Job' settings/parameters, I have the section "Run this job", set to "Only when previous job has failed".

My results have been, that if the previous/default/basic testing passed, the detailed step is skipped. As expected.

But if the previous step fails....the following new detailed step does not kick off.

Is it possible because the step is set up that if it fails hard stop and does not even evaluate the next step?

Or is it because the previous step says 'partially succeeded'. is this basically seen not as a failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Because failed is equivalent of `eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Failed')` status. But partially succeeded is `eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'SucceededWithIssues')`.

Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#failed).

You may try custom conditions like :

```yaml
in(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Failed', 'SucceededWithIssues')
```

[image]

Comment: I was wondering about those Custom Conditions..I had no idea it had anything to do with that OAuth setting.. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I am assuming that Agent.JobStatus already exists and doesn't need to be defined? Am I correct? Or do I have to add something somewhere for this, because it still is not kicking off, it is still saying it is waiting for the previous one to complete.

Comment: @GregP I assume you have now full solution. Am I right?

Comment: Actually I do not, very close. I found that the Status is for the current agent/task. I want the status from the previous step. All the examples are in YAML....but I don't see a yaml option for the release tasks. So wondering how I can set a variable from the previous task, to be consumed by the following task. Any direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the solution, a piece I missed was on the 'detailed' job, the 'Trigger even when the selected stages partially succeed', also needed to be checked, as well as the solution for the same step above.